# Perl script to add newline to end of textfile

Tags: linux, bash, perl, server, newline

I have tried to make a perl script add a newline to the end of a text file and then write in the following:

/bin/false

The file looks like this:

> /bin/sh
>   /bin/dash
>   /bin/bash
>   /bin/rbash
>   /usr/bin/tmux
>   /usr/bin/screen

I have tried running the following script:

> perl -pi -e 's///usr//bin//screen///usr//bin//screen"\n"//bin//false/g' /etc/shells

But without any luck. It does not accept the newline and just returns an error for the syntax. Can you help!?

Comment: `echo /bin/false >> /etc/shells`

Comment: Oh wow.. That simple!? Please make it an answer, than i will approve it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
s///usr//bin//screen///usr//bin//screen"\n"//bin//false/g
```

Indeed has  syntax errors. Starting from  the fact that you  used double
bars on  the path, where you  should have escaped them  (`\/`), and also
the strange newline string in the middle of it. You could also use other
delimiters rather than forward slash, to avoid having to escape all.

```
s!/usr/bin/screen\n!/usr/bin/screen\n/bin/false!
```

Also, don't forget  to close your last  line. And you can  also use `\K`
(see `perldoc perlre` for details) to  simplify your regex, with a final
result of:

```
s!/usr/bin/screen\n\K!/bin/false\n!
```

But anyway, this  seems to be overkill. You can  use your shell features
to echo a line and redirect to a file, by appending with `>>`:

```
echo /bin/false >> /etc/shells
```